# Future of PivotViewer control and HTML 5 equivalent

Tags: silverlight, pivotviewer

As Silverlight's future seems to be quite unsure, does anybody know if the PivotViewer control will still be maintained and updated?

I wish to develop an application based on this amazing control but I am not confident whether it will be maintained or not.

Is there any HTML5 initiative for developing such data visualization behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: I know it's an old question, but I still get asked about PivotViewer after all these years. It was an immensely powerful and novel platform for exploring large data sets of images - which is why I'm still actively working on similar technology.
Zegami a complete rewrite that addresses many of the fundamental issues with PivotViewer. Zegami can handle collections up to 50k items, is mobile responsive and has a documented plugin architecture. Have a look at some of our example collections demo.zegami.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that Silverlight as a whole will be "maintained and updated" for *years*.

There is so much talk of the death of Silverlight, but it and XAML are still top-tier Microsoft technologies. Nothing should stop you using the PivotViewer control and Silverlight in your application. If, in several years you're still working on the same thing and you feel support is lacking, cross that bridge then and reassess this decision.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I am also confident that these technologies will remain for several years. If you're aware of a simlilar pivot control in HTML 5 (maybe an open source project) I'll be interested.

Comment: You might find this [post](http://forums.silverlight.net/post/621578.aspx) useful. Someone has had a go at a HTML/JS version.

Comment: Excellent! I have also heard from some internal MS sources that the MS Pivot team is currently working on a HTML 5 version. It's good news:).

Answer (score 10):

I've been working on a HTML5 version of PivotViewer for a while now, you can see it here: http://pivot.lobsterpot.com.au/html5.htm.
This first prototype version doesn't have pan or zoom, but I do have a later version in the works that supports pan, zoom and tile templates.

Comment: Oops looks like I broke it when I was cleaning up old collections - all fixed now. Also see http://pivot.lobsterpot.com.au/pass2012.htm for a more up to date version.

Comment: Hi Roger, What if there will be 5000 item in pivot viewer? There is no scroll  in HTML5 pivot viewer.

Comment: I'm no longer working on the HTML5 PivotViewer and it is now being maintained by OpenLink Software - https://github.com/openlink/html5pivotviewer. Instead I'm now working on Zegami a complete rewrite that addresses many of the fundamental issues with the HTML5 PivotViewer. Zegami can handle collections up to 50k items, is mobile responsive and has a documented plugin architecture. Have a look at some of our example collections http://demo.zegami.com.

Comment: Thanks for reply @RogerNoble I'll try to use Zegami.

Comment: @RogerNoble, would you be so kind as to point us to where you got the original code for the port? Has Microsoft released the source code for the original Silverlight PivotViewer?

Comment: I'm now working on Zegami (http://zegami.com/) which is a significant improvement on both the Silverlight and HTML5 versions of PivotVIewer.
The source code for the original HTML5 PivotViewer is on GitHub and maintained by OpenLink Software - https://github.com/openlink/html5pivotviewer. Microsoft has not released the source code for the Silverlight PivotViewer, but they have released seajax which is another PivotViewer port https://github.com/seajax/seajax

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but this control has been one of those awesome ones. The lobsterpot control is open sourced on github by openlink:
https://github.com/openlink/html5pivotviewer

if you're a budding dev for js, fork and improve :)

Answer (score 0):

There's an HTML5 version of PivotViewer around now by members of the original team that made the Silverlight version. It's sad that there is no WPF and WinRT version of it by Microsoft btw.

see links I've gathered on PivotViewer here
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kf7pir9gf0wwdwy/AABmsm5LDcGYoA7UDGH33tTha?dl=0
those were collected during the development of ClipFlair project (http://ClipFlair.net - see http://clipflair.codeplex.com for the source code). Choose the "Gallery" option to see Silverlight PivotViewer in use there inside a zoomable floating window container that can host other components too along with it.